# Microsoft Script Control - Blocking scripts' access to the system?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, security

I am developing a commercial VB.net WPF application that needs user generated scripts for controlling the application to be shared between users. The best way that I have come across of accomplishing this so far without writing my own parser is using the Microsoft Script Control.

It would appear that both VBScripts and JScripts run through this control have access to wscript and as a result are too powerful to be shared between programmers and non-technical users for obvious security reasons.

I have considered trying to filter out dangerous scripts with some kind of regex parsing or something but that just seems far too risky and easy to circumvent.

So, is there some way of using this control but blocking its access to the system so that it could be used for controlling only the objects that I give it? If not, could someone recommend a better way of doing this?

I do not particularly mind what language the script would be in at this stage, although having multiple options would be nice.

**EDIT:** I am basing my conclusion that the control is too powerful for this on the fact that the following JScript code successfully launches notepad when called using the .AddCode and .Run methods of the control.

```
function test(){
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
    shell.run("notepad.exe", 1);
}
```

Thanks for all the help,
Sam.

Comment: re: *It would appear that both VBScripts and JScripts run through this control have access to wscript* - I do not believe this to be true. What leads you to this conclusion?

Comment: Well, I initially came to the same conclusion as you but when I built a little test app that took a script that used it as a string and loaded and ran it it did appear to work. I did do this late at night though... Damn I will hate myself if I got that wrong :D Testing again now...

Comment: I can confirm that it is too powerful in its current form, see the edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to kill the ActiveXObject feature which is the entry point to the system, you can silently append some lines to the code you give to the Script Control, like this for example:

```
ActiveXObject = null; // add this silently

function test(){
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell"); // this will now fail
    shell.run("notepad.exe", 1);
}
```

Of course, if you still need to give some functions to your users, you will then need to propose some sort of an API, use the AddObject function (see [How To Use the AddObject Method of the Script Control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185697)), and the user would use it like this:

```
ActiveXObject = null; // add this silently

function test(){
   // this is a controlled method, because I have added a MyAPI named object
   // using AddObject, and this object has a OpenNotepad method.
   MyAPI.OpenNotepad();
}
```

PS: WScript is a, ActiveX Scripting *host*, so it's not accessible from the Script Control.

PS2: This hack does not work in every Script Control underlying languages. It works in JavaScript, but not in VBScript for example.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there might be a solution like this. I know how to handle all the AddObject stuff. But might there be other ways a user could get the same effect without ActiveXObject? I am just a little wary of blacklisting rather than whitelisting.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way, beside restricting the user with standard Windows security measures (UAC, rights, etc...). But ActiveXObject is an efficient blacklist. Without it, you can't do much harm as Javascript was designed primarily for browsers, so it's implicitely sandboxed. And it only exists in Microsoft Javascrit implementation.

Comment: Ok thanks, well as long as blocking ActiveXObject is enough then that seems like a nice solution and would save me having to worry about licensing and stuff using Jint or something per Joe White's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I am just writing up my class using this now to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it doesn't look like you gave any consideration to any of the open-source script engines out there. I would suggest that those open-source libraries could solve your sandbox problem much more easily than the Microsoft Script Control.

The way I understand it, your requirements are:

- Must be able to pass objects from your program into the scripting environment, so the script can use those objects to interact with the host app.
- Must not be allowed to do unsafe things like access files, launch applications, create COM objects, etc.

Given those requirements, you have quite a few options.

The first thing that comes to mind is [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/), an open-source JavaScript interpreter written in .NET that you can embed in your app. You can pass .NET objects to the script. By default, the script can actually access any class in the .NET Framework, *but* the script is sandboxed by default (using .NET's built-in Code Access Security), so the script can't do anything unsafe. (For example, it could use things like StringBuilder or Regex, but it would get an exception if it tried to use FileStream.) If you want, you can disable the .NET access entirely, but even with it enabled, the default sandbox would probably suit your needs.

If for some reason Jint doesn't meet your requirements, some of the other open-source JavaScript-for-.NET engines I can think of off the top of my head are [Jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/), [IronJS](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS), and [JavaScript .NET](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/).

If it matters to you, Jint, Jurassic, and IronJS are all available through NuGet.